# cakephp 3.0 Auth & single sign on

Tags: authentication, cakephp-3.0

I am using cakephp 3.0 and in the login page although I try to enter the right credentials i get invalid username or password message.
In my user table , I have the fields username and password by which i want to authenticate user.
I have tried to follow the cake book documentation for 3.0 except the step where for including password hashing.Also used the table structure similiar to the one in cakephp documentation
Is it because it is accessing the wrong table?I have mentioned the fields in App Controller

Also if i have to implement single sign on ,is there a plugin which could help me out?Please provide links to such tutorials as this is important for my graduate studies project

My model file:

```
class UsersTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->table('users');
        $this->displayField('User_id');
        $this->primaryKey('User_id');
        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
    }


    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator
            ->add('id', 'valid', ['rule' => 'numeric'])
            ->notEmpty('id', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('username','Username is required')
            ->notEmpty('password','Password is required')
            ->notEmpty('role');


        return $validator;
    }


    public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
    {
        $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['username']));
        return $rules;
    }
}
```

My UserController file

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;
use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\Core\App;
use Cake\Event\Event;

class UsersController extends AppController
{ 

    public function view($id = null)
    {
        $user = $this->Users->get($id, [
            'contain' => []
        ]);
        $this->set('user', $user);
        $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
    }

    public function register()
    {
        $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                $this->Flash->success('The user basic details has been saved.');
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.');
            }
        }
        $this->set(compact('user'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
    }


    public function edit($id = null)
    {
        $user = $this->Users->get($id, [
            'contain' => []
        ]);
        if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                $this->Flash->success('The user has been saved.');
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.');
            }
        }
        $this->set(compact('user'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
    }


    public function delete($id = null)
    {
        $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);
        $user = $this->Users->get($id);
        if ($this->Users->delete($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success('The user has been deleted.');
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error('The user could not be deleted. Please, try again.');
        }
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }




    public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
    {
        parent::beforeFilter($event);
        // Allow users to register and logout.
        // You should not add the "login" action to allow list. Doing so would
        // cause problems with normal functioning of AuthComponent.
        $this->Auth->allow(['register', 'logout']);
    }

    public function login()
    {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $user = $this->Auth->identify();
            $this->set('user',$user);
            if ($user) {
                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                $this->Flash->error(__('Login successful'));

                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
        }

    }

    public function logout()
    {
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }

     public function index()
    {
        $this->set('users', $this->paginate($this->Users));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['users']);
    }
}
```

My AppController file

```
class AppController extends Controller
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');
        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'authenticate' => [
                'Form' => [
                    'fields' => [
                        'username' => 'username',
                        'password' => 'password'
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'loginRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Orders',
                'action' => 'view'
            ],
            'logoutRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Pages',
                'action' => 'display',
                'home'
            ]
        ]);


        $this->Auth->allow(['display']);
    }

    public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
    {
        $this->Auth->allow(['index', 'view', 'display','login']);
    }
}
```

My login page:

```
<div class="users_form">
    <?=$ this->Flash->render('auth') ?>
        <?=$ this->Form->create() ?>
         <fieldset>
            <legend>
              <?=_ _( 'Please enter your username and password') ?>
            </legend>
            <?=$ this->Form->input('username') ?>
              <?=$ this->Form->input('password') ?>
        </fieldset>
        <?=$ this->Form->button(__('Login')); ?>
        <?=$ this->Form->button(__('Register')); ?>
        <?=$ this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

Comment: So why didn't you follow the documentation examples exactly? Password hashing is kinda essential here.

Comment: I have included a password hashing method in my model file,but it does not seem to help.

Comment: Can you please give us your database? Users table should be enough.

Comment: You need to make sure you can store all the characters from the hashed password in the  database. varchar(45) will nog work. varchar(255) will work.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong.
First place I had not included the password hasher method.
On trying to include that ,I added it to the wrong module.It must be added for the Entity class file whereas I was adding it to The UserTable.php.
This was not helping my case at all.I followed the manual to the T .
After adding the password Hasher module I added a new user.
Also it is true that it works only if the password length is varchar(255)
Therefore  the user along with hashed password was created.
I was then able to login